# Trisect a square on its sides. How many isosceles triangles can you find by connecting three of the dots?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

*As shown in the figure below, each pair of points on each side of the square trisect that side. How many isosceles triangles can be formed by using the 8 trisection points and the 4 vertices?*

[image: Figure 1]

How should I start "counting"? Or is there a better way?

My approach:

```
Let's name the dots: A, B, C, ... L from the top-left vertex.

The top-left vertex, which is point A, can form three triangles 
△ABL △ACK △ADJ

The similar applies to the other vertices, which gives s a total of 
12 triangles (3 triangles each for the four vertices)

Now for the trisection points. For point B, it can form a triangle △BHJ
Same for the other trisection points, which give us 8 more triangles.

Therefore we have 12+8=20 triangles in total.
```

So my answer is 20, which was not the correct answer given (36). What did I mis-count?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you want help here, please recollect what you "forgot" and [edit] the question to show us how you counted to get the answer you did. Then maybe we can help.

Comment: @Ethan Okay, I will try solving the problem again and post the solution on the post.

Comment: It's interesting that for a $n\times n$ square, the number is always $(2n)^2$ I have tried it from $1$ to $4$ (by brute force). There must be some really elegant solution.

Comment: $36$ by brute-force, code [here](https://tio.run/##ZVDLbsMgELzzFfS265LKjx4qq3yJ5QOOSbuuAwiIFPvnXWzXaaVeYHZhZ2fGTfHTmurN@WWhq7M@coraR2vHwJwlE4NsQIkO@cV6ngAn8/vlxXnb384RvDIfGl5ReO20irJETheuzAS0DjS5qNqNYSs3QmyZCiER8VEb2HehlEXJegqxlKO6dr3idzHV4XYFoNOAWVbuLGJYeWZykN4RmfJa/ZkQcw0/VVolzqKvVdafuuyMMDV5e7qnQ0xNsaKiFfOjNx89ZM4nSbCKCzrCxdtZmxURsoeT/0nsRo4cKuRsDSLJg4zwSeYplJ6zg3WzCoP42vNN4PBFgpqibp@pqZMYxHdZsnQtyzc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

The peak of the triangle can be a vertex or a trisection point. It is sufficient to analyze these two cases.

For the first case take the upper left vertex $A$ of the square, and write next to each other marked point its distance to $A$. Looking at the resulting numbers you should be able to find the number of isosceles triangles with peak at $A$.

Same for the marked point $B$ at one third of the upper edge of the square.

Now think of how many marked points of type $A$ you have, and how many marked points of type $B$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Draw diagonal lines that go from top-left to bottom-right to divide the square into two right triangles and four trapezoids. This gives six isosceles right triangles with the vertex of the right angle at the top-right and bottom-left vertices of the square.

Likewise, draw diagonal lines that go from top-right to bottom-left to divide the square into another two right triangles and another four trapezoids. This gives six isosceles right triangles with the vertex of the right angle at the top-left and bottom-right vertices of the square.

The total number of isosceles triangles formed is thus $12$.

Comment: How about [this](https://i.imgur.com/Ct3zLWk.png)?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin The picture and the code you commented before are amazing. Thanks!